# How to bond NIC on a virtual machine?

Tags: xen, nic, bonding

I'm puzzled about this process. Historically when I've setup an LACP bond on a piece of physical hardware I have to create the analogous setup on the switch. How does this work with a virtual machine (Xen, VMWare, whatever)? How would it be handled if one machine wanted to bond several NICs while others didn't?

Comment: What are you goals in bonding? There may be other modes you can setup that don't require switch config

Comment: Goal is to provide room for more traffic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you don't do the bonding on a virtual machine, you do it on the hypervisor. You then present the bonded interface to the virtual machines as a single interface.

Comment: This is what I did (Xen 6.2). I have a shared storage on a 10Ge network via two bonded NICs. There are 4 other 1Ge NICs available also. I didn't change anything on the switch when I setup the 10G pair and it's working fine. This  might be Xen or Equallogic doing some magic but adding this pair to a VM doesn't work. Still trying to debug it.

Comment: You do have to set up the switch with a hypervisor the same way you did with a physical server. Otherwise, it should work the same.

Comment: V strange that it's working then.

Comment: Which mode did you select when creating the bond? 6.2 offers 4 options, not all of them require switch support. Only the 2 LACP options require switch support.